# An equality involving a moving surface $\Sigma (t)$

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Given a surface $\Sigma(t)$ that moves in space over time, a vector field $ \boldsymbol{B}=\boldsymbol{B}\left( x,y,z,t \right) $, and $\mathrm{div} \boldsymbol{B}=0$. $ \boldsymbol{V}$ is the velocity field on the surface.

Prove that
$$
\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}t}\iint_{\Sigma \left( t \right)}{\boldsymbol{B}\cdot \text{d}\boldsymbol{S}}=\iint_{\Sigma \left( t \right)}{\left[ \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{B}}{\partial t}+\left( \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{V} \right) \boldsymbol{B}+\left( \boldsymbol{V}\cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{B}-\left( \boldsymbol{B}\cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{V} \right] \cdot \text{d}\boldsymbol{S}} 
$$

It seems difficult for me to deal with problems involving moving surfaces. Also the formula above is seemed to relate to [Stokes' theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes%27_theorem). **How to prove the formula? And can we generalize it to [manifolds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold)?**

Comment: I do not wish to solve it right now - but I would like you to take a look at Reynold transport theorem, which may help to take the derivative of your integrals. The first thing which you have the desire for executing is to take the derivative of $B$, but you have moving surface or the one which changes over time. That means you would have to add your obtained integral $\int_{\Sigma(t)} \partial B/\partial t dS$ to another one, where you take the derivative of the domain: $\int_{\partial \Sigma (t)} B \cdot (v^b \cdot n)dS$.

Comment: To get it right, just transform your surface integrals to volume ones and apply the Reynold formula.

Comment: I took a look at the Reynolds transport theorem, there are physical proofs but not mathematical ones. Could you please explain in a pure mathematical way?

Comment: what do you wish to know about? In Wikipedia, you should look up Reynold theorem. There you should find the proof of the theorem in the mathematical sense. To get the maximum understanding, I would recommend you to write the proof down in your textbook and analyze each step of it until you can derive the idea of the formula on your own. Note: You should know about Jacobian, which is used there.

Comment: I mean a more general sense in mathematics. I asked how to generalize it to manifolds in the question

Comment: I got you! You wish to know about the generalization of differentiating integrals over time-dependent surfaces. To save your time: Read here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#General_form:_Differentiation_under_the_integral_sign

Comment: ok, I'll read that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I will give a sketch on how to find such a general formula for manifolds, but for those who don't know much about differential geometry and Lie derivatives, this answer will be pretty pointless, and definitely not enlightening at all. Not sure if this is what you are searching for, but here we go:

Let us work in $\mathbb{R}^3$ as ambient space (not that this is needed in the actual math going on, but just to fix the ideas) and let $\omega_t \in \Omega^2(\mathbb{R}^3)$ be a smoothly varying family of two forms. Moreover let $M_t = \phi_t(M)$, where $M$ is a two dimensional manifold and $\phi_t$ is the flux of some velocity vector field $X$. Finally, we denote by $\phi_t^{*} \omega$ the classical pull-back of the form $\omega$ by the diffeomorphism $\phi_t$. Then we have
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{M_t} \omega_t &= \frac{d}{dt}\int_{M} \phi_{t}^*(\omega_t) = \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{M} \frac{\phi^*_{t+h}(\omega_{t+h}) - \phi^*_{t}(\omega_{t})}{h } \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{M} \frac{\phi^*_{t+h}(\omega_{t+h}) - \phi^*_{t}(\omega_{t+h}) + \phi^*_{t}(\omega_{t+h})- \phi^*_{t}(\omega_{t})}{h } \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{M} \phi_{t}^* \left( \frac{\phi_h^*(\omega_{t+h})-\omega_{t+h}}{h} \right) + \phi_t^*\left(\frac{\omega_{t+h}-\omega_t}{h} \right) \\ &= \lim_{h \to 0} \int_{M_t}  \left( \frac{\phi_h^*(\omega_{t+h})-\omega_{t+h}}{h} \right) + \left(\frac{\omega_{t+h}-\omega_t}{h} \right) \\ &= \int_{M_t} \mathcal{L}_{X}(\omega_t) + \dot{\omega}_t \, , 
\end{align}
where $\mathcal{L}_{X}(\omega_t)$ is the Lie derivative of $\omega_t$ with respect to the vector field $X$. By Cartan's magic formula then
\begin{align}
\frac{d}{dt}\int_{M_t} \omega_t &= \int_{M_t} \mathcal{L}_{X}(\omega_t) + \dot{\omega}_t = \int_{M_t} i_{X}(d\omega_t) + \int_{M_t} d(i_{X}\omega_t) + \int_{M_t} \dot{\omega}_t \, ,
\end{align}
and this is kind of the most general formula you can hope for. Now note that:

1. The $\omega_t$ corresponds to the term $\frac{\partial \textbf{B}}{\partial t}$ in your right hand side.
2. Since $\text{div}(\textbf{B})=0 $ then $d\omega_t=0$ and the first term cancels.

Finally, to be honest as a mathematician I have no clue on what the notation
$$ \left( \nabla \cdot \boldsymbol{V} \right) \boldsymbol{B}+\left( \boldsymbol{V}\cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{B}-\left( \boldsymbol{B}\cdot \nabla \right) \boldsymbol{V} $$
actually is supposed to mean, but I strongly believe that this is what comes out by the term $ \int_{M_t} d(i_{X}\omega_t) \,$.

I hope that this gives at least the idea of where all these magic formulas about the integration of moving things come from. Long story short, once you have defined integration of forms, then integrating on moving surfaces is just the same as pulling back the integrand via the velocity flux, then one just computes the derivative inside the integral, since the domain of integration does not depend on time anymore.

Answer (score 1):

THe formula is in accordance with the material derivative idea:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial t} \int_{\Sigma(t)} \vec{B} d\vec{S} = \int_{\Sigma (t)} \left(\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} + \nabla \vec{B} \cdot \vec{v} \right) + \int_{\partial \Sigma (t)} \left[\vec{B} \times \vec{v}\right]d\vec{s} $$
Now use the formula for transforming line integral into Surface one. How? We know that
$$\int_\gamma \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{s} = \int_{\Sigma} \left[\nabla \times \vec{F}\right] \cdot d\vec{\Sigma}$$
Then you transform the last integral and use that
$$\vec{\nabla} \times \left[\vec{B} \times \vec{v}\right] = \vec{B} \cdot \left(\nabla \cdot \vec{v}\right) - \vec{v} \cdot \left(\nabla \cdot \vec{B}\right)$$
Plugging this into the equality above yields desired formula.
NB! This is not material derivative, given by $\frac{D}{Dt} = \frac{\partial}{\partial t} + \vec{u}\nabla$ where $u$ is vector velocity of fluid. In your example, the velocity of the domain that changes over time.

Comment: For now, I leave my answer as an attempt at direct computational process. The 2d answer provided by another person is the one you seek! Have a great day!

Comment: Thanks for your help :D